# How can I do count on number of occurrences of each distinct value of a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

List of students enrolled in courses. In each course there could be x homeworks.
I need count of homeworks for each course for each student.

Eg:
Sample table

```
Mark      Math        hw1
David.    Math        hw2
Mark.     Science.    hw1
Mark      Math.       hw2
David.    Science.    hw1
David.    Literature. hw1

Expected results (3 columns)

    Mark | Math    | 2 (because two math homeworks) 
    Mark | Science | 1 home work
    David| Math    | 1 home work
    David| Science | 1 home work
    David| Lit.    | 1 home work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, course, count(*)
  from your_table
 group by name, course
```